# Show implicit function satisfies the following propety

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

> Assume the equation $f(\frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{z})=0$ defines an implicit function $z=g(x,y)$, and that all functions are differentiable. Show that
>   $$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$$

**My attempt**: Define $u(x,y)=\frac{x}{z}, v(x,y)=\frac{y}{z}$. Then

$$f'_x=\frac{f'_v}{z}-\frac{z'_y}{z^2}(f'_u x + f'_v y)$$
$$f'_y=\frac{f'_u}{z}-\frac{z'_x}{z^2}(f'_u x + f'_v y)$$

I tried to isolate $z'_x$ and $z'_y$ but that didn't yield anything.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: By the way I found a solution online but it assumes $z$ is an independent variable which doesn't seem right due to the constraint $z=g(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we write $F(x,y,z) = f(x/z,y/z)$. If we assume that $\partial F/\partial z\ne 0$ on $F=0$, then by the implicit function theorem this equation defines $z$ locally as a differentiable function $g$ of $x$ and $y$. Morever, we have the formula
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = -\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}},$$
and similarly for the $y$ partial. But by the chain rule, writing $f=f(u,v)$, we have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x/z,y/z)\cdot \frac 1z \qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x/z,y/z)\cdot \left(-\frac x{z^2}\right)+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x/z,y/z)\cdot \left(-\frac y{z^2}\right).$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x/z,y/z)\cdot \frac1z.$$
Then (with $z=g(x,y)$ inserted throughout)
$$x\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + y\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = -\frac{\frac xz \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} + \frac yz\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot \left(-\frac x{z^2}\right)+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot \left(-\frac y{z^2}\right)}=z=g(x,y),$$
as desired.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled as $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and you treat it as if it was an independent variable which could achieve any value. How come?

Comment: This is how the implicit function theorem works. You have a function $F$ of independent variables $x$, $y$, $z$. Only the constraint equation  $F(x,y,z)=0$ relates them. Think about it in two dimensions. On the circle $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1=0$, we have $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{\partial F/\partial x}{\partial F/\partial y} = -\dfrac yx$, as implicit differentiation tells you.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\partial_{x}\left[f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)\right]=\partial_{1}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{g\left(x,y\right)}-x\frac{\partial_{x}g\left(x,y\right)}{\left(g\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}}\right)-\partial_{2}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)\cdot y\frac{\partial_{y}g\left(x,y\right)}{\left(g\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}}=0$

and $\partial_{y}\left[f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)\right]=\partial_{2}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{g\left(x,y\right)}-y\frac{\partial_{y}g\left(x,y\right)}{\left(g\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}}\right)-\partial_{1}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)\cdot x\frac{\partial_{x}g\left(x,y\right)}{\left(g\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}}=0$

Thus subtracting the above two equations: $\left(\partial_{1}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)-\partial_{2}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{1}{g\left(x,y\right)}=0$

Thus writing $c\left(x,\, y\right)=\partial_{1}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)=\partial_{2}f\left(\frac{x}{g\left(x,y\right)},\,\frac{y}{g\left(x,y\right)}\right)$
  we have $$c\left(x,y\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{g\left(x,y\right)}-x\frac{\partial_{x}g\left(x,y\right)}{\left(g\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}}-y\frac{\partial_{y}g\left(x,y\right)}{\left(g\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}}\right)=0$$
 $$c\left(x,y\right)\cdot\left(g\left(x,y\right)-x\partial_{x}g\left(x,y\right)-y\partial_{y}g\left(x,y\right)\right)=0$$
 and thus: $$g\left(x,y\right)-x\partial_{x}g\left(x,y\right)-y\partial_{y}g\left(x,y\right)=0$$

qed

Comment: How did you claim that these derivatives are equal to $0$? The fact that $f(\frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{z} )=0$ doesn't mean $f_x=0$ but rather $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(\frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{z} )=0$

Comment: It is not $f_x=0$ but the derivative of the whole expression with respect to $x$. I write $\partial_1 f$ for $f_x$.

Comment: I added some brackets. - You are right, my notation was ambiguous, now it should be clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!